# Python 3: Run several scripts and parse strings between them

Tags: string, python-3.x, interface

I want to develop a bot for a '[Four In A Row game](http://theaigames.com/competitions/four-in-a-row) in python 3. There is no downloadable game engine in python 3, so I wish to create my own. Since my bot must ultimately work with the official game engine there isn't a lot of flexibility in the interface.

The engine must be callable like this

```
python game_engine.py bot1.py bot2.py
```

This would start a game instance that pits bot1 against bot2.

Communication between the scripts is by passing strings back and forth in a way similar to `sys.stdin`.

My question is: How do I setup the scripts such that `game_engine.py` can send and recieve strings to `bot1.py` and `bot2.py` independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module in the standard library.

The Popen command is what you probably want here